# Desarrollo de módulo prestashop, ¿cómo descargar fichero .csv?

Tags: php, prestashop

Necesito que el usuario descargue un fichero .csv  Para ello le pongo el enlace

```
 <a href='ruta/fichero.csv' download='fichero.csv'>Descargar</a>;
```

A pesar de que estoy seguro de que la ruta está bien, me da el siguiente error:

> "This page is not available We're sorry, but the Web address you've entered is no longer available."

Answer (score 0):

El enlace te envía a una página que no existe (como una página de la tienda). Prueba con el atributo **target** para abrir una página nueva:

```
<a href='ruta/fichero.csv' target='_blank' download='fichero.csv'>Descargar</a>;
```

Utiliza una ruta absoluta al fichero. Otra cosa que puede fallar es la localización del fichero, si esta dentro de la estructura de directorios protegidos de prestashop te impdesira la descarga, al tiempo que interpresa que vas a una página inexistente. Utiliza una ruta accesible, p.e. https://www.tutienda.com/puclic/fichero.csv

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu respuesta. El problema era que el fichero que quería descargar tenía 0KB, al elegir uno con algún dato lo descarga sin problemas.